# Angularjs - Required field validation of ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJs 1.3.4, I am trying to validate ui-select control. This control is wrapped inside an ng-repeat. Below is my ui-select

```
 <ui-select tagging tagging-label="new tag" multiple ng-model="data.value" theme="bootstrap" name="value">
              <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter values..">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
              <ui-select-choices repeat="tags in vm.availableTags | filter:$select.search">
                {{tags}}
              </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
```

I tried adding below but it did not work

```
required and ng-required="true"
```

After reading few posts I added hidden input as below with the same name as ui-select:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="data.value" name="value_{{$index}}" class="form-control" required />
```

The above code works but the issue is when you type something in the ui-select and then delete the one you selected/typed it passes validation and does not throw error.
Ideally it should return isValid for false but it returns true.

I have created a demo for my issue here:    http://jsfiddle.net/zfLy86bt/2/

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was an interesting one, the issue is that when you initially load data into the field, it creates and array under the "value" property.  When you remove that entry, or tag, it leaves the empty array and that seems to be enough to be considered to fulfill the required check.

I added a controller function to delete the property when the value array is empty:

```
vm.clearData = function(data) {
    if (data.value && data.value.length == 0) delete data['value'];
}
```

I then used ng-change to call it from the ui-select element and that seemed to work, the fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8a1jnfmu/)